# snapkit login kit not working Swift Xcode 11.3.1

Tags: swift, ios13, snapchat, snapkit, xcode11.3

I am using Xcode 11.3.1 and try to login with snapchat with loginkit I add the add information in info.plist and my code is

```
  SCSDKLoginClient.login(from: self, completion: { success, error in

                        if let error = error {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                            return
                        }

                        if success {
                            self.fetchSnapUserInfo() //example code
                        }
                    })
```

this code show me the login ui of snapchat and I am login into snapchat with my account.
but I am stuck on this ui
[image]

when I am click on continue nothing is happing . **SCSDKLoginClient completion** block not called.

Comment: Check this url

https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/bsc7jw/problem_with_snapchat_snap_kit_returning_to_app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello everyOne soo finally i found the **solution**

i am using 11.3.1 and when i create new project the add 
**AppDelegate** and **SceneDelegate**  default class.

so according to snapchat logkit documentation i add

```
  func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                       open url: URL,
                       options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
          return SCSDKLoginClient.application(app, open: url, options: options)
      }
```

method in my **Appdelegate** class. but this method never get called in **xocode 11.3.1**
so the solution of my problem is this

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
   guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
       return
   }

     SCSDKLoginClient.application( UIApplication.shared, open: url, options: nil)
    }
```

you need to add this method into your sceneDelegate file. then everything work fine.
synpchat need to update there  doc for new **xcode 11.3.1**.  i hope this answer help you guy's because i also wast my 3 day's on this issue. 
**happy Coding** :)

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked but unfortunately `SCSDKLoginClient.application( UIApplication.shared, open: url, options: nil)` this code does not authenticate the user in. How did you solve it?

Comment: @airsoftFreak i am not understand  your point . can you explain it ?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure your URL scheme is configured correctly.

[URL Schemes](https://www.appcoda.com/working-url-schemes-ios/)

Comment: url scheme configured correctly my app is laughing from snapchat    app but the callback  not responding.